# Why do MySQL foreign key constraint names have to be unique?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've noticed that I can't create two different foreign key constraints that have the same name, regardless of the set of tables in the schema that they're affecting.

Which I can cope with that, I couldn't find in the MySQL documentation where it says this is the case, nor *why* its the case.  I'm using InnoDB, so maybe it's something specific to that, but I'm not finding that documented either.

Comment: *If the CONSTRAINT symbol clause is given, the symbol value, if used, must be unique in the database. [...] If the clause is not given, or a symbol is not included following the CONSTRAINT keyword, a name for the constraint is created automatically.* -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That's the answer I was looking for. Why not make it an actual answer, so I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: Unless I am missing something this doesn't tell you _why_.

Comment: The fact that it says it must be unique in the database is what I was looking for.   Someone else mentioned that the constraints can be referred to directly by name without a table, so that's another reason they need to be unique.