# Migrations - Duplicate key on write or update - Only for Test Env

Tags: laravel

A project I am working on uses a mysql db for both testing & development (different db). When running `php artisan migrate:refresh` everything works fine.

However, when running tests it fails to run all migrations with the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `cmstatic_test`.`#sql-5008_121` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (SQL: alter table `project_user` add constraint `project_user_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Here is my migration up method

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('project_user', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id');

            $table->foreign('project_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('projects')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('roles');
            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I don't get how there can be a duplicate key set for this table.

My tests look like

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class AuthTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    ...
```

### Update:

if I remove

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

The tests can be run again. However, I want that foreign key relation -.-

### Update2:

I checked the table structure after removing the line that adds the foreign key and obviously the foreign key is not set. So no other migration is doing the same.

Comment: Are you sure tht error is from this db migration?

Comment: As said - when removing the line that I posted below "update" it works fine ... It's really weird, I did a lot of projects with laravel and never had this before.

Comment: I've also tried to seperate the foreign key definition from the table creation. Still same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I had 2 tables

1. page_translations
2. pr_page_translations

*I had all sympthoms described in 1st post. I don't believe there can be an "error" in DB. So I searched and found the cause.*

There was a foreign key named "page_translations_page_id_foreign" in table #1. When I was trying to add FK with same name to tabe #2 I got my "duplicate" error. So I added "pr_" prefix to FK name in table #2 "pr_page_translations_page_id_foreign".

Another solution that also worked for me was to rename already existing FK in table #1.

Conclusion: **FK names across all tables must be unique**.

After this I searched for explanation, and here it is: [Why do MySQL foreign key constraint names have to be unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569804/why-do-mysql-foreign-key-constraint-names-have-to-be-unique)

Comment: That's a nice finding! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function up()
{
    if (!Schema::hasTable('project_user')) {
        Schema::create('project_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id');
            $table->foreign('project_id')
                ->references('id')->on('projects')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')->on('roles');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was an error with my database itself. I've deleleted the tables multiple times and tried it again and the error was still there.

> However, deleting the whole database and re-creating it solved the
>   issue.

This might be interesting for anyone facing this issue aswell.

Comment: It's better to use migrations than deleting manually. Sometimes manual process makes us stuck somewhere.

Comment: I do have the migrations to the delete the tables. But deleting the tables didn't help. I had to delete the whole database itself.